# Issue in odoo 8 displaying warning message

Tags: api, warnings, decorator, odoo, onchange

I am trying to validate a "capacity" field with onchange decorator but for some reason when I send the warning message the previous line stops working. The template updates the field fine whitout the warning

```
@api.onchange('capacity')
def check_capacity_values(self):
    if self.capacity<0:
        self.capacity=0
        raise Warning(_('wrong capacity.'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary as return value for methods decorated by `api.onchange`. The key for warning messages will be `warning` and the value another dictionary with keys `title` and `message`. An example:

```py
return {
    'warning': {'title': "WARNING!",
                'message': "It isn't allowed to have a negative capacity!"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem may be that the change you made in self.capacity just before raising the warning is not stored in the database because you are using @api.onchange, so the new value is just shown in the UI, but not stored in the database.

Try it using @api.depends instead, the change will be reflected both in the UI and the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.onchange('capacity')
def check_capacity_values(self):
    if self.capacity<0:
        self.capacity=0
        return {'warning': {
                    'title': "Warning",
                    'message': "message",
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.